# What is the most efficient way to filter numbers and parentheses in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to filter the number and parentheses out of the following string:

```
firstText secondText probablyMoreTextToComeWithSpacesBetweenThem (0000)
```

I want the output to be:

```
firstText secondText probablyMoreTextToComeWithSpacesAndNumbersBetweenThem
```

What is the fastest and most efficient way to do this in JavaScript? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I want only the numbers between the parentheses to go away and not any other number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace()`

```
var s = "firstText secondText probablyMoreTextToComeWithSpacesBetweenThem (0000)";
    s = s.replace(/\(\d*\)/g, "");
```

Comment: This regex matches `1()`, but not `(1)` nor `(12)`. See Bergi's answer

Comment: please let me update the answer :) I've just read the update on the question

Comment: This also removes `()`, I'd replace `*` (`{0,}`) by `+` (`{1,}`)

Comment: @Lekensteyn from the question it s' not clear if `()` would be allowed or not. In the update Loolooii asked  *I want to filter the number and parentheses and only the numbers between the parentheses to go away and not any other number.*

Comment: @F.Calderan, this works when I test. So I'm going to accept the oldest answer.

Comment: @Bergi looking at the first phrase on the question, my answer was fine and worked anyway before OP clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your input, this [regex](http://regular-expressions.info/) could work:

```
return input.replace(/\s*\(\d+\)/g, "");
```

It [replaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) all parenthesized integers, including all whitespaces before, with an empty string. To remove just all brackets and digits from your string, use

```
return input.replace(/[()\d]/g, "");
```

Comment: I just updated my question with something important I forgot to mention. Sorry.